# zsh Interpret/ignore commands beginning with '#' as comments

Tags: command-line, zsh

In bash, if I type a command beginning with a `'#'`, bash ignores it as a comment.

Ie, the following is ignored at the bash prompt:

```
> # Hi there!
```

Whereas in zsh:

```
> # Hi there !
zsh: bad pattern: #
```

How can I ask zsh to do the same?

This is incredibly useful to "store" commands that you want to run later, or to chat when using a shared tmux/screen session.

I am using '[oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check if the `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` option is set.

According to [this](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/info2html?%28zsh%29Comments) page, "[...] in interactive shells with the `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` option set, [...] `#` causes that word and all the following characters up to a `newline` to be ignored."

---

According to the comments were added later, `set -k` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: This was "set -k" on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, "set -k" and "setopt interactivecomments" both work.

Comment: Updated link to source http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html