# Is there a way to use the pound sign '#' as an alias?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

Can the .bash_aliases file accept an alias that is of the form of `alias #='./'`

I've tried quotes and escaping the character too, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in bash? In zsh works.

Comment: What are you trying to solve ? `#` is start of shell comment. So `alias  #='./'` is equivalent to invoke `alias` command with some comment in right side.  Regarding to `zsh` mentioned in comment above, please refer this, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33995/64403

Comment: I wanted to make # as the command line command to execute a C object file. So instead of ./name_of_file arg1 arg2 I type in #name_of_file arg1 arg2

Answer (score 3):

Do this :

```
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$ shopt interactive_comments
interactive_comments    on
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$ shopt -u interactive_comments
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$ shopt interactive_comments
interactive_comments    off
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$ alias #='ls -la'
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$ # /tmp -d
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 32768 Nov  2 03:09 /tmp
xb@dnxb:~/tmp$
```

In ~/.bash_aliases, escape it:

```
shopt -u interactive_comments
alias \#='ls -la'
```