# How to map # to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME?

Tags: shell, zsh

Much like `~` is representative of `$HOME`, how can I make `#` (or some other symbol; `#` is not occupied by default in `zsh`) stand for `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`?

```
[~] % #/zsh<enter>
[~/.config/zsh] %
```

Comment: octothorpe (`#`) introduces a comment. `~` is not just for `$HOME`, `~dmr` is the home directory of user `dmr`, `~-` is $OLDPWD.

Comment: As I said, by default `#` is meaningless in `zsh`, `~` standing for `$HOME` is a time saver, and I `cd` into `$HOME/.config/..` just as much and a similar shortcut would prove useful to me.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33994/5132 for why the premise of this question is wrong.

Comment: @JdeBP "`#` or some other symbol", said I. I do not use `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS`, and hash seemed to me the best fit. This is but a red-herring, If I can get `_` or `@` to work, I'd be happy as those three are the only symbols my shell does not utilise.

Comment: What you actually wrote was "`#` is meaningless" and "`#` is not occupied".  Moreover, `@` _likewise_ can have a pattern matching rôle in the Z shell.

Comment: You are right, @JdeBP, I could word it better, but the premise of this question is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to /u/OneTurnMore, one possible way of roughly doing this is:

```
[~] % hash -d _=$HOME/.config
[~] % ~_
[~_] % pwd
/home/me/.config
```

`hash -d _=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` works but does not change the prompt.